# Where is the internal memory for Samsung Galaxy S2 and how do I remove it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I've removed the motherboard like this: http://gyazo.com/9995b3ba45b8053c2732eee6f62f90da

I no longer care about the phone itself. The only thing I particularly care about now is getting into the internal memory since it has alot of sentimental files that really can't be replaced. A picture pointing out the things i need to take out would be nice as well as some additional info

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The internal memory isn't removable - it's soldered onto the phone's motherboard. The only way to get data from it is via USB.